# check if a vector is in a struct

Tags: matlab

If I have a struct, for example:

```
vars =
    var1: [3 1 3]
    var2: [2 2 8]
    var3: [2 3 4]
    var4: [1 4 5]
```

How can I check if something like `vec = [2 2 8]` is somewhere in the struct? Or if a number like 1, is there?

Answer (score 2):

### Searching by field name

You can use [`isfield`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html) to search by field name:

```
isfield(vars,'vec')
```

will return `true` if `vec` is a field of the structure `vars`.

### Searching by field value

This is quite a bit more complicated. You have to first get all the fields from the structure, then loop through them all and compare them to your data of interest. Here's an example, it may not be the most efficient or elegant one, but it should work:

```
% Data
vars.var1 = [3 1 3];
vars.var2 = [2 2 8];
vars.var3 = [2 3 4];
vars.var4 = [1 4 5];
vec = [2 2 8];

% Get field names
names = fieldnames(vars); % I assume you do not know a priori what fields are in vars

% Go through the fields in the structure
idx = false(length(names),1);
disp_str = '';
for k=1:length(names)
    if isequal(vec,vars.(names{k}))
        idx(k) = true;
        if isempty(disp_str)
            disp_str = names{k};
        else
            disp_str = [disp_str ' and ' names{k}];
        end
    end
end

% Display the results
if max(idx)>0
    disp(['Match found in ' disp_str]);
else
    disp('No match found')
end
```

Comment: Then `vec` is not a field of the structure. You only have 4 fields `var1`, `var2`, `var3` and `var4`, but no `vec`.

Comment: Oh, so I can't see if a particular number is in var1? And if it's not than in var2, var3...?

Comment: Check the documentation for `isfield`: it searches if a field in the structure has the **name** specified, not the **value**. You didn't say in your question you wanted to search by value, I assumed you meant by field name.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it now. So there's no way to search the values?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, I need some time to think about it.

Comment: You could make this more concise using `struct2cell` and `cellfun`. For example: `s = vars; idx = cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, vec), struct2cell(s)); matchedFields = names(idx); disp_str = strjoin(matchedFields, ', ');`. `Struct2cell` is like `fieldnames()`, but extracts the contained values instead of names.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Thanks for the suggestion, it's a good one. Feel free to put it as an answer, I'll upvote it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`structfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) to apply a function (i.e. equality check) to each field of a scalar structure:

```
>> vars = struct('var1',[3 1 3],'var2',[2 2 8],'var3',[2 3 4],'var4',[1 4 5])
vars = 
    var1: [3 1 3]
    var2: [2 2 8]
    var3: [2 3 4]
    var4: [1 4 5]
>> testVec = [2 2 8];
>> b = structfun(@(f)isequal(f,testVec),vars)
b =
     0
     1
     0
     0
```

And change the function to suit your purpose.  For example, `ismember`,`intersect`, `any(f==scalar)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is more interesting than it seems to be.

The answers above only works if the size of vec is equal to the size of the vectors in the struct. What about the second part of the question: *"Or if a number like 1, is there?"*

Try the following code. It searches for the occurrence of a vector (of any size) in the field values of a struct.

```
function [fields, ismember] = ipl_ismemberofstruct(struct, needle)

% Get needle string
needle_str = ipl_getmatstr(needle);

% Retrieve field names from struct
fields = fieldnames(struct);

% Prepare some variables
ismember = false(1, length(fields));
delimiters = ' ;';

% Loop through each field looking for needle
for i=1:length(fields)
    [fieldvalue_str] = ipl_getmatstr(struct.(fields{i}));
    [contains] = ipl_strcontains(fieldvalue_str, needle_str, delimiters);
    ismember(i) = contains;    
end
end

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function [contains] = ipl_strcontains(haystack, needle, delimiters)

contains = false; 

% Get occurrences of needle on haystack
idxs = strfind(haystack, needle);

% Verify each occurrence (just whole occurrences are taken into account)
for i=1:length(idxs)

    % The character before needle must be a delimiter (or the haystack begins with needle)
    before_idx = idxs(i) - 1; 
    before_clear = true;   
    if(before_idx > 0)
        k = strfind(delimiters, haystack(before_idx));
        if(isempty(k))
            before_clear = false;
        end
    end

    % The character after needle must be a delimiter (or the haystack ends with needle)
    after_idx = idxs(i) + length(needle);   
    after_clear = true;    
    if(after_idx <= length(haystack))
        k = strfind(delimiters, haystack(after_idx));
        if(isempty(k))
            after_clear = false;
        end
    end

    % If both variables are true, then needle is a 'whole' occurrence
    if(before_clear && after_clear)
        contains = true;
        return;
    end    
end
end

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
function [matstr] = ipl_getmatstr(mat)

% Convert matrix to a string
matstr = mat2str(mat);

% Remove '[' and ']' characters, if they exists
if(numel(mat) > 1)
    matstr = matstr(2:(length(matstr)-1)); 
end
end
```

**Use case 1: Vector [2 2 8] is inside field var2**

```
vars = struct('var1',[3 1 3],'var2',[2 2 8],'var3',[2 3 4],'var4',[1 4 5])
vars = 

    var1: [3 1 3]
    var2: [2 2 8]
    var3: [2 3 4]
    var4: [1 4 5]

[fields, ismember] = ipl_ismemberofstruct(vars, [2 2 8])
fields = 

    'var1'
    'var2'
    'var3'
    'var4'


ismember =

     0     1     0     0
```

**Use case 2: Scalar value [2] is inside fields var2 and var3**

```
[fields, ismember] = ipl_ismemberofstruct(vars, 2)

fields = 

    'var1'
    'var2'
    'var3'
    'var4'


ismember =

     0     1     1     0
```